# using the same validator for different attributes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I have a custom validator that I want to apply to several attributes in the same model

right now I the following the works just fine:

```
 validates :first_name, validator_name: true
 validates :age, validator_name: true
 validates :gender, validator_name: true
```

But when I try:

```
validates :first_name, :age, :gender, validator_name: true
```

The validator will run for the first attribute (:first_name) but not the others. Is this possible to achieve? I spent hours googling this but haven't found any examples

```
module Person
  class SomeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      return unless can_do_something?(record, attribute)

      #... more code 
    end

   def can_do_something?(record, attribute)
      anything_new = record.new_record? || record.attribute_changed?(attribute)
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: You use `validator_name` in the model, but your validator is `some_validator`. Is it typo or you have different validators?

Comment: Probably `can_do_something?` is not about validation but about authorization layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this should just be a comment or if it constitutes an answer; however what you are requesting...

> I have a custom validator that I want to apply to several attributes in the same model

...is how an `EachValidator` works.

So what you are describing...

> The validator will run for the first attribute (:first_name) but not the others.

..cannot be accurate.

For Example:

```
require 'active_model'
class StartsWithXValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value.match?(/^(?:\d+\s|^)X/)
      record.errors.add attribute, "must start with X"
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  
  attr_accessor :name, :city, :street
  
  validates :name, :city, :street, starts_with_x: true
end
```

In this case all three attributes will be validated through the `StartsWithXValidator`.

e.g.

```
person = Person.new({name: 'Xavier', city: 'Xenia', street: '123 Xenial St'})
person.valid? 
#=> true

person_2 = Person.new({name: 'Benjamin', city: 'Philadelphia', street: '700 Market St'})
person_2.valid? 
#=> false
person_2.errors.full_messages 
#=> ["Name must start with X", "City must start with X", "Street must start with X"]
```

[Working Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/ValidatesEachExample#main.rb)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a custom method validation:

```
  validate :validate_person

  def validate_person
    [:first_name, :age, :gender].each do |attr|
      validates attr, validator_name: true
    end
  end
```

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: [`ActiveModel::validates`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) is a class method not an instance method so this will cause a `NoMethodError`. You could technically implement using a loop but not the way it is presented in this answer.

Comment: Also I think it's not good idea to combine validations like this, as well as attributes into an array, due to reduced readability